# Open Gstatus in new tab

Tags: command-line, plugin-fugitive

I am using the [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) plugin and I encounter a strange behaviour. I don't know if it's really related to the plugin or not.

I am trying to open the `Gstatus` page in a new tab. So I am creating a new tab and call Gstatus on the new tab :

```
:tabnew | Gstatus
```

And I get the following error :

```
E492: Not an editor command: Gstatus
```

Do you know what might cause the issue and how to fix it ? 
I can create a function to achieve this behavior, but I wanted to keep a mapping like the one I currently use :

```
nnoremap <Leader>gs tabnew | Gstatus<CR>
```

**Edit** :

- When starting vim inside a git directory without a file, the `Gstatus` works.
- When creating a new tab and running `Gstatus` by hand, the command failed, even if the `pwd` command shows the good directory.

Comment: Well, it's probably because when you create a new tab, you are also in a new buffer ... and `:Gstatus` needs the *current* buffer to be under version control (git).

Comment: I understand, but if I run the `Gstatus` command by hand after the `newtab` the command runs without problem

Comment: I just tested (with `tabnew`) and it doesn't. This is consistent with the docs `:h fugitive-commands`

Comment: My bad, it doesn't. I must have tested with a file open. I edited my question

Comment: BTW, `Gstatus` *should not* work without a file, even if in the right folder. It's the first item on the FAQ: https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive

Comment: Right, but as my edit stated, the `Gstatus` work event when I open vim without a file... Can it be a config-specific trouble ?

Comment: Does it work anytime you are in a git directory, afterwards (i.e. during a Vim session, no loaded buffers)? In any case, the docs specifically say that that is not the intended behavior. So, I don't know what do you expect.

Comment: I tried the following : `vim tracked_file` : `Gstatus` works. Then I open a new buffer and I close the existing one with `new` and `quit`. And now the `Gstatus` doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, `Gstatus` *only* works with a tracked file loaded as the current buffer ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `<c-w>T` to promote a window to a new tab.

```
nnoremap <Leader>gs :Gstatus<cr><c-w>T
```

For more help see `:h CTRL-W_T`

Comment: Or, purely in terms of commands, `:Gstatus | wincmd T`.

Answer (score 5):

I'll just quote from the official plugin FAQ:

> FAQ
>
> Q: I installed the plugin and started Vim. Why don't any of the commands
>   exist?
>
> A: Fugitive cares about the current file, not the current working
>   directory. Edit a file from the repository.
>
> Q: I opened a new tab. Why don't any of the commands exist?
>
> A: Fugitive
>   cares about the current file, not the current working directory. Edit
>   a file from the repository.

It doesn't matter if you are, or not, in a Git controlled folder. `:Gstatus` is a buffer-local command, it will only be available if the currently loaded buffer deals with a file which is under git revision control. Therefore, when you open a new tab, the current buffer is an empty one, and `:Gstatus` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

The question is old, but the answers are either not optimal or wrong.

The VIM command `tabnew` creates a new a buffer in a new tab. You should use only `tab` command, like so:

```
nnoremap <Leader>gs <CMD>tab Git<CR>
```

Good luck on your VIM journey.

Comment: Indeed, the `:tab` modifier will execute the command that follows in a new tab. For those who don't require a mapping, `:Gstatus` is now replaced by `:Git` or `:G`, so one could quickly type `:tab G`